# Order topology and subspace topology in $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

let $X=(-\infty, -1) \cup [0,\infty)$, subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Then is it different from  the order topology? Say $(-1/2,1) \cap X =[0,1)$ is open in $X$, but not open in the order topology??

---

I once questioned it... but still confused

so, [0,1) is not basis for order topology on X?( not open in order topology on X?)

Comment: That's right, it's not open. Pretty sure you asked this before awhile ago.

Comment: @MattSamuel thank you! then, order topology must be connected??

Comment: It is. If it were $(-\infty,-1]\cup [0,\infty)$ it would not be connected though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes $[0,1)$ is not a basis for the order topology because a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for the order topology should contain all sets of the following types:

1) All open intervals $(a,b)$

2) Intervals of the form $[a_1,b)$

3) Intervals of the form $(a,b_0]$.

Then only we call the set a basis.